# How to embed Facebook Like button to the uploaded Video on the webpage?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have developed a Facebook application in which every user uploads or provides a link to a  YouTube video.

I want to list all the uploaded videos on a page along with a like button for each video.

Can any one guide me how to embed like button for more than one uploaded video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually Create FB Like link e.g.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.domain.com/video.php?123" data-send="true" data-width="350" data-show-faces="false" style="margin-left:5px;"></div>
```

Create a page video.php and place this code

```
<script language="javascript">
window.location.href='http://www.facebook.com/pages/facebook_page_name/page_id?sk=app_XXX';
</script>
```